# Web request timeout in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am trying to make a web service request call to a third part web site who's server is a little unreliable.  Is there a way I can set a timeout on a request to this site?  Something like this pseudo code:

```
try // for 1 minute
{
    // Make web request here
    using (WebClient client new WebClient()) //...etc.
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use the [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) property:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
request.Timeout = 1000; //Timeout after 1000 ms
using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

---

UPDATE:

To answer the question in the comment section about `XElement.Load(uri)` you could do the following:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds");
request.Timeout = 1000; //Timeout after 1000 ms
using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var xel = XElement.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know how it works.  Can I put this all in a try catch statement so that I can return an error message if it times out?

Comment: Of course, putting try/catch is what you need to handle the exception and return a proper message.

Comment: This may be for another question, but do you know how I can also use this with Xelement.Load(uri)?

Comment: @victor_foster seeing as how this is tagged asp.net-mvc. Whilst you can set the timeout on the webrequest IIS might still cut the request that initiated the action of. Don't forget to set the timeout on the current HTTP request (that invoked your action) too. In debug mode the default timeout is a year but in a release build IIS will default to 90 seconds.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Thanks I'll try it out.

@Martijn Laarman, can give you me link on how to update this as well?  90 seconds might be for this particular application but it would be nice to be able to set it as needed.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I am parsing a same page using htmlagility in a foreach , means htmldocument.load(url) is called in a foreach with different url every time, but it throws timeout exception on this line, i just want to minimize the timeout , i have tried to minimize timeout duration using request.timeout=5000 , i.e after 5 seconds , but it is timming out in 3 minues no matter how much value i set.

Answer (score 4):

WebClient does not naturally support custom timeouts. But you can easily build a derived class with custom timeouts:

```
public class TimeoutWebClient : WebClient
{
    private int _timeOut = 10000;
    public int TimeOut
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeOut;
        }
        set
        {
            _timeOut = value;
        }
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        webRequest.Timeout = _timeOut;
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Source: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/maniknet/archive/2008/06/16/Ganz-kurz_3A00_-WebClient-mit-eigenem-Verbindungs-Timeout-_2800_WebClient-with-a-custom-connection-timeout_2900_.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should go with

```
System.Net.WebRequest.Timeout
```

property

Answer (score 2):

You could check for WebTimeout exception from server side then use SignalR to actively send timeout messsage back to clients:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.your_third_parties_page.com");
request.Timeout = 1000; //Timeout after 1000 ms

try
{
    using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
         Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
    {
         //If timeout then send SignalR message to inform the clients...
         var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHub>();
         context.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage("This behavious have been processing too long!");
    }
}
```

See more [how to setup SignalR for asp.net here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Answer (score 0):

Many classes within .Net framework that involve any kind of networking include a Timeout property. For instance, there's such a property on the WebRequest class (System.Net)